# "Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid" Impersonation & UAC

Tags: c#, windows-7, process, uac, impersonation

I have written a program that needs to be run elevated to invoke two methods of a WMI object. Works like a charm if run by an user from the administrators group in "elevated mode". But now the problem is it needs to be run by everyone and not everyone has administrative privileges on the machine they work on. So I decided to let the program restart itself impersonating a user from the "Domain Admins" group.

My code for that is as follows:

```
 ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
 proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
 proc.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath; ;
 proc.UserName = "USERNAME";
 SecureString secure = new SecureString();
 foreach (var item in "PASSWORD")
 {
     secure.AppendChar(item);
 }
 proc.Password = secure;
 proc.Domain = "DOMAIN";
 proc.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.Verb = "runas";
 Process.Start(proc);
```

There are two problems with that when UAC is enabled.
First if I do not explicitely add the user which should be impersonated to the ACL of the installfolder of the program (user is already in Administrators group which has full access to the folder and all files contained in it) it throws a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid`.
I double checked the directory path and it is in fact valid (and works when user is in ACL explicitely).

Now if the user is added explicitely and there is no exception the program runs as the user but not with elevated rights so the invocations don't work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

I knowthere are a few questions about similar issues already but none of the solutions / answers solved my problem or they were not detailed enough and inactive for too long.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, this is all an attempt to bypass UAC. If that's correct, then you're trying to bypass something that is designed not to be bypassed.

Comment: @AbqBill Are you sure it isn't possible for a program running with low privileges to restart itself with high privileges by using the login of an Domain Admin? Do I really have to make a service and let the service execute the actions via interprocess communication?

Comment: I would be surprised if it were possible as this would be a potential (and fairly trivial) attack vector. Also, check the UAC tag in SO and sort by FAQ (this is frequently asked). Your solution (create a service that runs elevated) seems to me to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: @AbqBill It seems to be possible because if you look at the included "tools" in metasploit there are serveral programms to bypass UAC or elevate you from standard user even to sytem. The problem thou is that I do not want to provide the user with these programs. I would like to integrate this functionality in my program to prevent abuse.

Comment: But I think I will split my program in a GUIapp and a service anyway because I really do not want to put all that effort in to make my program bypass UAC just to be then deleted by the virusscanner or something like that.(Also I really do not want to put any effort in virus scanner evasion...)

Comment: My guess is that these "tools" will require membership in Administrators to begin with, which is not what you should depend on your app anyway. (One of the purposes of UAC is to get developers to stop assuming that users are members of Administrators.)

Comment: @AbqBill I dont think so. These tools are post exploitation tools. Their purpose is to elevate your session on an compromised machine from normal user or whatever the session you compromised runs as to local system or local admin. If they would require your session to already be elevated what would be the purpose?

Comment: There is a difference between being a member of the local Administrators group and running elevated. With UAC enabled, it's not enough to just be a member of Administrators; you also have to run elevated. The exploits of which you speak are trying to bypass the UAC elevation prompt to run elevated will succeed only when the user is already a member of Administrators. They will fail if the user is not already a member of Administrators.

Comment: I don't recommend trying to bypass the UAC prompt as it is not something that is designed to by bypassed, nor do I recommend trying to figure out how to perform an unauthorized escalation of privilege. Instead I think your proper course is to separate your app into two parts (GUI and service), as you mentioned.

Comment: I already have rewritten my program as described above (service + guiapp). I am testing the escalation purely to see if it is possible and/or how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been having the same problem, I could not elevate AND provide credentials at the same time. In order to use 'runas' verb you have to set UseShellExecute=true but in order to provide credentials you have to have it set to false.  What I ended up doing is testing for admin rights and if they are not present restarting my application as a separate user who had local admin rights.  Then I would run the process.start with the 'runas' verb and without the need to provide credentials.  At this point your user will receive a UAC prompt and after selecting yes the process will run elevated.  I wrote mine in VB but the idea is the same, here is my code, the IsUserAdminGroup was used from:

[UAC self-elevation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBUACSelfElevation-39b7606f/sourcecode?fileId=52933&pathId=1873630815)

---

```
     Try
    'check if user is administrator
    Dim fInAdminGroup As Boolean = Me.IsUserInAdminGroup
    If (Me.IsUserInAdminGroup = False) Then
    'check if process is running under user you want to elevate
        If Not (System.Environment.UserName = "") Then
    'this process restarts the app as the desired admin user
            Dim path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
            Dim filename As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    'create secure string password
            Dim passwordPre As String = ""
            Dim passwordChars As Char() = passwordPre.ToCharArray()
            Dim password As New SecureString()
            For Each c As Char In passwordChars
                password.AppendChar(c)
            Next
            Dim procInfo As New System.Diagnostics.Process
            procInfo.StartInfo.FileName = filename
            procInfo.StartInfo.UserName = ""
            procInfo.StartInfo.Domain = ""
            procInfo.StartInfo.Password = password
            procInfo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    'load user profile was needed for a legacy application I used that failed without the user hive loaded
            'procInfo.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = True
            procInfo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            procInfo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path
            procInfo.Start()
            Application.Exit()
        Else
            MsgBox("Unable to open, call support.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Run Failed")
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    ElseIf (System.Environment.UserName = "") Then
        Me.Visible = False
        Me.Hide()
    'this process starts the desired app elevated
        Dim procInfo As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        procInfo.StartInfo.FileName = "ptpublisher.exe"
        procInfo.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
        procInfo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        procInfo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        procInfo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Primera Technology\PTPublisher"
        procInfo.StartInfo.Arguments = ""
        procInfo.Start()
        Application.Exit()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Run Failed")
    Application.Exit()
End Try
```